# •Error(40,14): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

•Error(40,14): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ( - + case mod new not null continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date pipe

Comment: Provide the SQL that failles

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This is a syntax error. Your program won't compile until you fix the code. Probably it is a missing semi-colon or similar typo.

Looking at the code we have written and spotting our own bloomers  is a crucial programming skill. The code gives you a big clue: you must look at the lines of code around line 40.

---

> "There is a parameter at line 39 which stored procedure is expecting and which is not getting passed by trigger. Will that can cause an issue ?"

Maybe. It is hard to visualise the problem without seeing the code. Why don't you make the change and see for yourself?

Comment: There is a parameter at line 39 which stored procedure is expecting and which is not getting passed by trigger. Will that can cause an issue ?